# how to add redshift jdbc driver to aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

i am having a lambda function which access and queries redshift table. but i am getting 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver" while testing the function. how do i add redshift jdbc42 driver jar to this lambda function

Comment: Did you try grabbing the driver from [Download the Amazon Redshift JDBC Driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver)? If that fails, can you please show us the relevant code that you are running? (Just the bits related to the JDBC connection.0

Answer (score 0):

You can package that in the zip file that you use to create lambda function
Packaging structure should be as follows

```
.
|-- com
|   +-- amazonaws
|      +-- lambda
|         +-- demo
|            +-- redshiftuser.class
+-- lib
    |-- RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i have created a jar file and uploaded it to create a lambda function, but still it is showing the same error

Comment: package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
//import com.amazonaws.;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class redshiftuser implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

Comment: public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
     //Redshift driver: "jdbc:redshift://x.y.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev";
     //or "jdbc:postgresql://x.y.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev";
          final String dbURL = "jdbc:redshift:xxxxxx/dev1"; 
          final String MasterUsername = "xxxx";
          final String MasterUserPassword = "xxxxxx";
          String TenantID = null;
          String Email = null;

Comment: // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt1 = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{
//Dynamically load driver at runtime.
 //Redshift JDBC 4.1 driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
   //Redshift JDBC 4 driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc4.Driver
 Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");

   //Open a connection and define properties.
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   Properties props = new Properties();
//Uncomment the following line if using a keystore.
//props.setProperty("ssl", "true");

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be all jumbled up. Can you please paste that in the question itself using the 'code' block. That way it will maintain its formatting

Comment: @sri Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm doing the same, wondering how to get the redshift driver in a Java lambda